# Stepping through entities in Python 3.3 html.parser

Tags: python, html-parsing, python-3.3

I have the following Parser:

```
class Parser(HTMLParser):

  def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.tableCount = 0

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
     if tag == "table":
       for attr in attrs:
         if attr[0] == "class" and attr[1] == "space":
           ## need to do some processing here
```

In place of the comments, what I need to do is step all the HTML entities after this point until the end of the `table` tag (this code is only run when `tag == table` as shown above.

How would I do that? I cannot see any way to step through the all the tags under this tag. Please note I cannot use any external library such as BeautifulSoup (just Python standard library).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.inTable = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "table" and ('class','space') in attrs:
            self.inTable = True
        if self.inTable:
            doSomething()

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "table":
            self.inTable = False
```

I guess `xml.etree.ElementTree` might be easier to use for this kind of situation.